# Paperclip is not saving the original file when a style is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm working to make Paperclip store a thumbnail in addition to the original image. The original image had always saved file and now I'm trying to add a thumbnail.

The problem is, once I defined the style thumbnail, the original is no longer being saved. How can I get the original to save along with the thumb?

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :attachment,
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "s3.yml",
  :s3_protocol => 'https',
  :s3_permissions => :private,
  :use_timestamp => true,
  :default_style => :original,
  :default_url => '/images/:attachment/default_:style.png',
  :path => "/:rails_env/private/:basename.:extension",
  :styles => {
    :thumb => "100x100#" },
  :convert_options => {
    :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip" }
```

Answer (score -1):

Install **Imagemagic** (`https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip`) and then you can rezize your original sized photo into any size by using like this

```
<img src="#", size: '150x150'>
```